# Php header function doesn't show the error message

Tags: php

I am trying to catch the error messages from the URL using the header functions in php.
if i use the path like below, no error message is displayed in the url.

`header("Location: ../login-page/login.php?error = RegistrationSuccessfull");`

but the following works
`header("Location: ./login.php?error = RegistrationSuccessfull");`
The only problem with using this statement is my other files are maintained in such a directory format, for each functionality I have created a separate folder.

Help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean, "no error message is displayed in the url"? And what exactly is displayed instead?

Comment: Also, this kind of messages is a **very bad practice**. If you really want to display such a useless message, then you have to use flash messages, not URL

Comment: It just redirects to the page.
Doesn't display the "error" message.

if I use just ./login.php as the path, the error msg that I get is the following,
```login.php?error%20=%20RegistrationSuccessfull```
the only problem is my login.php is in a separate folder.

Comment: Most likely you have another useless redirect somewhere. You should really stop that bad habit of redirecting on every step.

Comment: I am not implementing this for commercial purposes, just getting to know php, html, and css

Comment: How it makes ANY difference? Or, rather, all right, what's the point in getting to know bad  php, html, and css?

Comment: Yep, you were right!
I had redirected somewhere else.
Thank you.

I learned by making a mistake.